# ImageMagick - How can I calculate disk cache and memory usage?

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to resize ten 21 GiB PSB-images on Windows 10 using ImageQuick 7:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-31 Q16 x64 2018-05-07 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

Image details:

```
d:\magick identify -verbose extreme.psb
Image: extreme.psb
  Format: PSB (Adobe Large Document Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 70866x53291+0+0
  Resolution: 6000x6000
  Print size: 11.811x8.88183
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: MSB
  Depth: 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 16-bit
    Green: 16-bit
    Blue: 16-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 3776520006
[...]
```

I did some math using [ImageMagick's formula](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#cache) (under "Cache Storage and Resource Requirements"):

> width * height * bit-depth / 8 * channels

which would make the cache file 30,212,160,048 bytes large.

Then trying to resize the image:

```
d:\magick extreme.psb -resize 95% extreme.tiff
```

But, it still halts (after 15 minutes) with a message saying:

```
magick: unable to extend cache 'extreme.psb': No space left on device @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3673.
```

The SSD-disk has 48 GiB available for cache - 60 GiB including the original image. Even if the cache file is 30 GiB, it would still have 18 GiB left.

**How can I foresee the total size necessary to process (any) images?**

On a side note: As you can see, I was able to run `identify -verbose` on it, which also created a 21 GiB temporary file. So I am thinking that there might be more temporary files than meets the eye.

Comment: Does it have to be psb? libvips can resize 100gb+ tif/png/ppm images easily, but not psb, sadly.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. The photographer is using a Nikon camera that can only store it AS PSB for 6,000 dpi.

Maybe I got confused about the settings. I'm trying 10% instead of 90 which made a 21.0 GiB and 2.1GiB temp files, instead of two times 21. I'll post the result here.